# A page can have only one server-side Form tag Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Aspx page as requested**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/tier6a-educ.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    EnableEventValidation="false" CodeFile="TAP_rubform_response.aspx.cs" Inherits="TAP_rubform_response" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="test1" runat="server">
    <head>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <div style="padding-left: 10pt">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <asp:Table ID="Table11" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow10" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 1: STANDARDS AND OBJECTIVES</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table38" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow11" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell11" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label23" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow34" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell44" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label48" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label49" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table12" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow12" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell12" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 2: Presenting Instructional Content</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow13" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell15" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label21" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow39" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell49" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label58" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label59" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table13" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow14" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 3: Lesson Structure and Pacing</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow15" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell18" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label25" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow35" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell45" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label50" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label51" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table14" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow16" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell14" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 4: Activities and Materials </h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table4" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow17" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell21" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label27" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow36" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell46" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label52" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label53" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table21" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow18" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell16" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 5: Academic Feedback</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table5" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow19" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell24" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label29" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow37" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell47" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label54" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label55" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table26" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow20" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell59" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 6: Grouping Students</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table6" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow21" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell27" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label31" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow38" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell48" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label56" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label57" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table32" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow40" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell71" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 7: Teacher Content Knowledge</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table7" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow23" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell30" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label32" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label33" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow24" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell31" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label35" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table39" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow42" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell91" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 8: Questioning</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table8" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow26" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell34" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label36" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label37" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow27" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell35" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label38" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label39" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table45" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow50" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell105" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 9: Thinking</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table9" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow29" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell38" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label40" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label41" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow30" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell39" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label42" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label43" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table50" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="845px">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow56" runat="server" orderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt"
                BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell117" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2"><h4>SECTION 10: Problem Solving</h4></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="table10" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="Gray"
            BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted" Width="850px" Style="line-height: 15pt"
            Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11pt">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow32" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell42" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label44" runat="server">Rating &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label45" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow33" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell43" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label46" runat="server">Evidence &nbsp;       </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label47" Font-Bold="true" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table15" runat="server" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1pt" BorderStyle="Dotted"
            Width="850px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow48" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell101" HorizontalAlign="left" ColumnSpan="1" runat="server"
                    Font-Size="Large">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Send As e-Mail" runat="server" OnClick="SendAsEmail_Click"
                        Font-Size="10pt" Height="18pt" Width="90pt" ValidationGroup="onsubmit" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell19" HorizontalAlign="center" ColumnSpan="1" runat="server"
                    Font-Size="Large">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" Text="Save As PDF" runat="server" OnClick="SaveAsPDF_Click"
                        Font-Size="10pt" Height="18pt" Width="90pt" ValidationGroup="onsubmit" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        </form>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have an aspx page and inside that I have a button that when the user clicks the page is sent to the user as an email.

This is the code I have written for the button's click function

```
protected void SendasEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxx");
    smtpClient.Host = "xxxxxxx";
    smtpClient.Port = 25;
    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.To.Add("xxxxxx");
    message.Subject = "The webpage is below";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = sw.ToString();        
    smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```

I can receive the email fine but after the page is executed, the following error is displayed.

I am absolutely there is only form within the page because if the implementation of the above function is empty,I do not get any error. The webpage loads fine and clicking the button does nothing.

**A page can have only one server-side Form tag.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): A page can have only one server-side Form tag.]
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnFormRender() +8721176
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +33
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
```

It seems like this error is because I am making the function call `this.Page.RenderControl(hw);`

Does anyone have any experience on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you calling `this.Page.RenderControl(hw);`?

Comment: so that I can get the contents of the page into the variable hw ( and variable sw indirectly) to copy into the 

message.Body = sw.ToString(); here

Comment: Can you also post your .aspx code?

Comment: @emmanuel-n : I have posted the aspx code

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you must have disabled `EventValidation` on your page, otherwise you'd be getting a `RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();` error.

What looks like is happening is that the page is being rendered in it's entirety into your `HtmlTextWriter`, and then re-rendered during the Render event to be outputted in the `Response`. This is probably causing ASP to see two Form tags and throwing the error. The solution would be to override the `Render` method of the page, capture the html you want, send it in the email and also write the html to the `Response` to be shown on the page.

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140018/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122006-1.aspx) has a good description of what's going on and how to override `Render`.

EDIT: You should be able to call `base.Render` and capture the output to write to the `Response` as well as your email.

In your button click, set a boolean value indicating whether to email the page:

```
public void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    okayToEmail = true;
}
```

And then when you override render, render the page into a new `HtmlTextWriter`, write the contents to the page's `HtmlTextWriter`, and check the value of the flag. If true, send the contents in an email.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            base.Render(htw);
            writer.Write(sb.ToString());

            if (okayToEmail)
            {
                using (var message = new MailMessage())
                {
                    message.Body = sb.ToString();
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember though: writing the entire page into the body of your email is probably not good... It will include the `Doctype` tag, the `html` and `body` tags, etc which will be stripped out by most (probably all) email clients. Also, linked stylesheets will not work, and I believe most email clients will strip out embedded stylesheets.

Comment: Maybe he should just create a new WebRequest to get the desired HTML?  Or use Server.Execute(). Rather than overriding Render... seems like that could have some negative side-effects; isn't this a method that only an ASP.NET host should be calling?

Comment: I tried the solution from the link that you posted, but I still get the same error. The overriden function that guy has used is this
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (okToSendMarkup)
            SendRenderedMarkup();

        base.Render(writer);
    }

so, it still calls the base.Render() when I get the error.

Comment: Check my edits. I'm assuming that your `SendRenderedMarkup` method re-renders the page which is causing your issue. My above edits work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to intercept and handle the response sent to the browser.
If you want to receive this response and process it you should use [Response filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx)

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // Filter the text to be rendered as all uppercase.
  Response.Filter = new UpperCaseFilterStream(Response.Filter);
}
```

The `UpperCaseFilter` class, a custom Stream class that converts all text that passes through it to uppercase.

Asp.net will call the `Write` method of the stream. You will need to do some buffering inside the stream class as it may receive data in chunks.